# How long answer can I write?

Tags: discussion, answers, answer-length

How long answer is considered OK in Stack Exchange sites? Are there any limits, assuming, that *entire* text of answer is somehow valuable and percentage of *blah, blah* is limited to minimum?

I have just wrote [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29123867/1469208) and I have doubts, if I didn't cross the line?

BTW: Is this the longest / one of the longest answer in Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow? :>

Comment: Oh, God! I'm not asking about **hard limits** -- _how many characters I can enter per one answer_! But about **soft limits**: what length of answer is reasonable, to not overkill reader. Can you see the difference? This is a question to make some dissuasion, to find limits, that suits most, not to read about how long answer body's field in database is. Answer linked as "duplicate" has nothing to with my question and does not deal with this at all.

Comment: That's going to be extremely subjective and highly dependent on context.  Nobody can really give you an answer in the abstract.

Comment: But' that's for meta discussions are, right? To discuss about subjective problems. Anyway, OK, I see the only way to get answer to this question, it to sit, wait and see, if my _long answer_ gets more upvotes or downvotes or is it going to be eventually closed. Thanks, anyway...